# WSO2 Governance Registry - Tenant Migration

Tags: wso2, governance-registry, wso2-governance-registry

I'm working in new GREG organisation, and I would like to copy resources from a already existent tenant to a new one. I've tried to use checkin-client (https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance530/Check-in+Client+Examples), but the resources aren't displayed. Are there a way to migrate data between tenants avoiding the handwork-copy-paste ?

I looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Can you view the resources from mgt console resource browser(http://i.stack.imgur.com/4rgTr.png)?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are two methods to do that

1) You can use tenant load method to make assets available to one tenant and visible to other tenants as well. But the problem is when using this method the assets will be shared across the tenants and the changes done from one tenant will be visible to other tenants as well. You can follow this http://emsooriyabandara.blogspot.com/2014/10/load-tenant-registry-in-carbon-component.html to do that.

2) You can use the GREG Rest API(https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance530/Registry+REST+API) to do that. As an example you can write a rest client to authenticate in source tenant domain and copy the asset using (https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance530/Resources+with+REST+API#ResourceswithRESTAPI-GettheContentofaResource) . Then use received API object to create an asset in destination tenant domain(after authenticating in destination domain) using (https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance530/Resources+with+REST+API#ResourceswithRESTAPI-AddaResource).

Hope this helps.